# NoMethodError: undefined method `sources' for #<Stripe::Customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I'm using [Stripe gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/stripe) for my payment method. According to its [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#retrieve_card) I did tried to retrieve the card which I added against a customer. Customer retrieval worked fine with

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve("cus_DWcUQOutnrAD4s")
```

but when I tried to retrieve card using

```
card = customer.sources.retrieve("card_1D5a3J2eZvKYlo2CDJ62mrSM")
```

It throws exception saying

> NoMethodError: undefined method `sources' for < Stripe::Customer: 0x007faae89500c0>

I googled much but could not find even the question like that which made me thinking that I might be the only person facing this issue. I am sure that `stripe` is installed correctly because I am successfully adding `customer`, `card` and `subscription` but it is the retrieval of `card` which throws the error.

Comment: I wonder if you're using an old version of Stripe's Ruby library. Does `customer.cards.retrieve` work? If you upgrade your Stripe ruby gem, does it retrieve as you expect?

Comment: @duck can you provide link for this version of documentation

Comment: @duck NoMethodError: undefined method `cards' for

Comment: if you `puts customer.id` or `puts customer.sources` does it output anything?

Comment: @ImranNaqvi have you got any solution if so please share it, Thanks

Comment: @maulikbafalipara as far I remember they replaced `sources` with `source`.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you would need to update your **Stripe Card methods** used for *Retrieve, add, List, Delete, Update*.

Here is the updated syntax to *retrieve* the **Customer Card** from **Stripe**

```
Stripe::Customer.retrieve_source(
  'cus_JApI6yov1S9L3n', # Here you should mention your customer id
  'card_1IYTe3SHXYB34571ooz7kV4t', # This will be the Card Id
)
```

Here is the sample result from above request:

```
{
  "id": "card_1IYTe3SHXYB34571ooz7kV4t",
  "object": "card",
  "address_city": null,
  "address_country": null,
  "address_line1": null,
  "address_line1_check": null,
  "address_line2": null,
  "address_state": null,
  "address_zip": null,
  "address_zip_check": null,
  "brand": "Visa",
  "country": "US",
  "customer": "cus_JApI6yov1S9L3n",
  "cvc_check": "pass",
  "dynamic_last4": null,
  "exp_month": 8,
  "exp_year": 2022,
  "fingerprint": "83DqOn8HS1c0rah5",
  "funding": "credit",
  "last4": "4242",
  "metadata": {},
  "name": null,
  "tokenization_method": null
}
```

You can go through the updated [Stripe API document](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/retrieve)